# How to stub accessors with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following class:

```
class TwitterService
  def initialize
    @twitter ||= Twitter
  end

  def get_short_url_length
    @twitter.configuration.short_url_length
  end
end
```

And the following spec:

```
describe TwitterService do
  before(:each) do
    Twitter::Configuration.any_instance.stub(:short_url_length).and_return(12)
  end

  it 'does not send short_url_length request to Twitter' do
    twitter = TwitterService.new
    twitter.get_short_url_length.should == 12
  end
end
```

The problem I have is that `#short_url_length` on `Twitter::Configuration` is not getting stubbed. Am I doing this wrong? All I'm trying to achieve is being able to run my `TwitterService#get_short_url_length` method without running the Twitter library, which causes a request to Twitter's API resulting in a fail.

I'm using the following tools:

- Rails 3.2.12
- Rspec 2.13.0
- Twitter 4.6.2

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your implemented, have you confirmed that @twitter.configuration is actually an instance of Twitter::Configuration?

Regardless, I think a better way to do this would be to inject a configuration into your code, i.e.

```
def initialize(config = Twitter::Configuration)
  @twitter ||= config
end
```

This can be a test double (mock or stub), or use the real service if none is specified.

Comment: When authentication data is set, @twitter.configuration is an instance of Twitter::Configuration. In Rails console, if I run `Twitter.configuration`, it actually authenticates with Twitter straight away. I think this is why I can't stub a method on it. I also can't pass config in as a parameter because it's part of the Twitter module.